# Merge Two Files in Weka based on date

Tags: weka

I have two datasets I want to merge together, with different attributes. One has about 4 million instances, the other has about 180.
They both have date attributes, and cover the same time period. The one with 4 million has a date attribute that covers day/month/year and time. The other one only has day/month/year. How can I merge these and have the smaller dataset copy its instances to every instance of the larger dataset, for that day?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Weka, what you want to do will be a nightmare. It's better if you try it on a programming language like R or Python. I would suggest you to try it on Excel, if your big dataset didn't have 4 million entries. The easiest way to do that is with Python Language and more specifically Pandas package.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunatly, i have almost no experience in python, or with manipulating CSV files like this, but I guess I should be able to figure it out, it doesnt sound too bad. I know java well, and I am thinking it might be easy to use that, but there might be some unforseen issues I havent thought of.

Comment: If you know Java well, Python will be a piece of cake for you.